# Use Actions.xml in android project

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Is there any android sample project available to demonstrate how to use Actions.xml in android project. The intention is I want to integrate google-assistant to my project.

Answer (score 1):

> With App Actions, your app can be recommended to users as a way to
>   fulfill their needs - at the moment they need it the most. By
>   registering your app to handle one or more user intents, users will be
>   able to see and interact with your app across multiple Google and
>   Android surfaces.
>
> Google provides a rich, ever-growing catalog of common intents. You
>   can associate capabilities and content in your app to the intents in
>   this catalog or define your own custom intents.[More](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions)

[**How to integrate actions in app**](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-integrate-actions-in-app-b3787eed283d)

[**Google Assistant SDK**](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/)

[**Quick Tip: How to Use Android's Assist API**](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-androids-assist-api--cms-27933)

[**Optimizing Contextual Content for the Assistant**](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant)

[**Top Answers on stackoverflow about Actions On Google**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actions-on-google?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Answer (score 0):

At Google I/O 2019, some updates were posted about App Actions:

- [Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/app/)
- [Google I/O 2019 session on App Actions (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQALSeGy9aY)
- [Sample application on github](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin)